# AngularJS custom validation not firing when changing the model programmatically

Tags: angularjs

I have created a custom validator for requiring a date to be in the past.  The validation seems to work great when entering the date manually into the field.  However, if I enter change the date programmatically (change the model directly as opposed to typing in the field), the validation does not fire.

I believe I am doing the custom validation directive as directed in the documentation.  [Here is a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jmcooper/jD929/) illustrating the problem.  In the fiddle, if you click the "Change date programatically" button, you can see the validation error doesn't get displayed (but it does if you change it manually).  Here is the directive code (also in the fiddle):

```
myApp.directive('pastDate', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function (viewValue) {
                var today = new Date();
                today = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate());

                if (new Date(viewValue) < today) {
                    ctrl.$setValidity('pastDate', true);
                    return viewValue;
                }
                ctrl.$setValidity('pastDate', false);
                return undefined;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are two ways of the model binding, `$parsers` controls the pipeline of view-to-model direction, and `$formatters` controls the pipeline of the model-to-view direction. When you update the model in the controller, the change goes through the `$formatters` pipeline.

I have updated your code to: [this](http://jsfiddle.net/jD929/27/), so it handles both ways.

```
myApp.directive('pastDate', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            function validate (value) {
                var today = new Date();
                today = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate());

                if (new Date(value) < today) {
                    ctrl.$setValidity('pastDate', true);
                    return value;
                }
                ctrl.$setValidity('pastDate', false);
                return value;
            }
            ctrl.$parsers.unshift(validate);
            ctrl.$formatters.unshift(validate)
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: @Terry yah, unfortunately you're going to miss the cakes in the office today.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, this makes a lot more sense now that I understand the difference between $parsers and $formatters.

Comment: Urgh, great answer. Was stuck on this for quite some time today. Only used the $parsers (view -> model) direction.

Comment: I was stuck for a day on this too and had to update a public directive I was using. Thank you!

Answer (score 11):

New answer since angular 1.3 provides `$validators` property.

Since 1.3, `$parsers` and `$formatters` are not supposed to set validity anymore, even if it still possible.

Then your code becomes simpler :

```
myApp.directive('pastDate', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            ctrl.$validators.pastDate = function(modelValue) { // 'pastDate' is the name of your custom validator ...
                var today = new Date();
                today = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate());
                return (new Date(modelValue) < today);
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Updated jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/jD929/53/

Comment: Using `$validators`, how can i access other scope properties or other fields in my form?

Comment: You can access all needed elements by using the `scope`, `element`, `attrs` parameters of the `link` function. As you are inside this function, these elements are available.

Comment: However, you cannot access other form fields. At least not in a simply way. But, theorically, the validation of a field should not depend on other fields properties. If you still need to, you should set a `$watch` of the source field property in the parent directive (the one with all the form) and, within, set a custom property in the field you need to validate. Then your validator will be able to see this custom property, as long as it is its own. Hope being clear enough...

Comment: 1) Inside `ctrl.$validators.myValidation`, the `scope`, `element`, `attrs` are undefined. 2) Based on your opinion, if my field validation depends on another field, then i should use `$parsers` and `formatters` ??

Comment: Give me a fiddle with your code and a minimal explanation of your goal. I cannot tell without seeing the existing code.

Comment: See this fiddle : http://fiddle.jshell.net/msieurtoph/fjxL75hu/ ... it tries to implement what you want and show you what is wrong ...

Comment: Thank you much for you help, i will compare my code with yours and see what is happening.