# Why $formatter executes after $watch

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am changing the value of my model from controller. I went through this post [AngularJS custom validation not firing when changing the model programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17621171/angularjs-custom-validation-not-firing-when-changing-the-model-programatically). The issue is $formatter is executed after $watch is executed.Why is that happening. Is there any other way to bind from model to view so that $watch executes after the bind has happened from controller.

what i understood is $parsers executes in the pipeline of view to model and then $watch is triggered and $formatters executes in the pipeline of model to view after $watch has already executed.

But i want something like $formatter to be executed before $watch or any alternative to it.